# How to get ellipsis with column-count style

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, markup

Is there a way to get ellipsis at the end of third column (produced by `column-count`) if content is clipped by `overflow: hidden;`.  The preferred way using CSS only. Something like:

```
data    data    data
data    data    data  
data    data    data  
data    data    ...

<ul style="list-style: none; -moz-column-count: 3; height: 5em; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
  <li>data</li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cL0xfvn0/)

Comment: See the update.  This how I expected it should work.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a table for your tabular data?

Comment: This is a list of keywords and I need to place it in a three columns within a fixed width and height box.  In case the number of keywords get out of the bounds I want to clip them and indicate that the list is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for `text-overflow` you can't do that:

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block
> container element in its inline progression direction (not text
> overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example).

*Inline progression direction* should be read as *from left to right* when the text direction is LTR.

Here's a dedicated, and not so old, article on the topic: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: The question is how to do the same for non-inline progression.

Comment: @loshadvtapkah I got the question. I'm just saying you can't. Not just with CSS, and not with the current state of the browser features. You can go for a JS solution, or wait some more years until the browsers will implement it.

Comment: Usually I do not work with markup, so I decided to ask if there is a solution I failed to google. There is so many non JS solutions now since the last time I worked with HTML&CSS.

Comment: @loshadvtapkah I understand your motivation, but unfortunately we don't have a native solution for this, yet.

Comment: A bit old, but still: So even if one of the parents has column-count setting, it doesn' work? For example here this is set on a block element with "inline progression" and it still does not. https://jsfiddle.net/k9ew7ry2/17/ True, one of the parent elements is not in the same flow ..